# exit python script if get an error while get and exit from subprocess

Tags: python, shell

I am currently working with a python script that in turn calls a shell script in between. The requirement is that, during the execution of the shell script, if any error turns out, then the shell script as well as the python script which has triggered that script has to exit.

Below is the code snipptet:

```
if re.match('(.+)' + text + '(.+)', line):
            output=subprocess.Popen(['sh', 'stest.bash'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        elif re.match('(.+)' + text1 + '(.+)', line):
            output=subprocess.Popen(['sh', '1.bash'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    ****---here if i get error in 1.bash script then i wants to stop the whole execution****
else:
    print("something went wrong!Please look into")
```

Below is the bash script:

```
if [soemthing]
then
 echo "something"
else 
 echo "exit" exit
fi
```

when the above script is ran and failed, the python script doesn't exit properly. Can someone point me as to what should be altered to get it fixed?

Comment: Please fix the formatting, mark the code and click the 'code format' button (looks like this: {}).

Comment: In the question, not as a comment. We need it to be understandable

Comment: please check now

Comment: The formatting is still invalid. The code in the "code window" should look exactly like your code. Indentation is incorrect. Do you need the value of output or is that only to see if successful?

Comment: i want that if my sub script faced any error then it should exit the whole script i.e. python script too.

Comment: And if it is successful, do you need the output?

Comment: no i do not need success output ...my need is only for error case if error then only exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to use `run`, if exiting using exceptions is okay:

```
if re.match('(.+)' + text + '(.+)', line):
    subprocess.run(['sh', 'stest.bash'], check=True)
elif re.match('(.+)' + text1 + '(.+)', line):
    subprocess.run(['sh', '1.bash'], check=True)
else:
    print("something went wrong!Please look into")
```

If you need to exit with returncode 0:

```
if re.match('(.+)' + text + '(.+)', line):
    return_code = subprocess.run(['sh', 'stest.bash']).returncode
    if return_code != 0:
        exit(0)
elif re.match('(.+)' + text1 + '(.+)', line):
    return_code = subprocess.run(['sh', '1.bash']).returncode
    if return_code != 0:
        exit(0)
else:
    print("something went wrong!Please look into")
```

also change your bash script to return a non-zero exit code on failure:

```
if [something] then
    echo "something"
else
    echo "exit"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: hi @SimonF its working. Thanks much. i tried with return code 0. Also please confirm if i can use the same if i am having another script under bash

Comment: @lucky I’m not sure what you mean, but all scripts should work as long as they `exit 1` on error. Also please accept answer

Comment: hi @SimonF its working. Thanks much. i tried with return code 0. Also please confirm  can i use the same if i am having another script under bash script.            
 for eg
 python calling sh1 and inside sh1 calling sh2 
and puting non zero return code in sh2.  will it work or need to change python file also?

Comment: As long as the script that python is calling returns non-zero exit code when you want the python script to end it will work.

Comment: i tried but its not exiting  the script in the case if i used below scenario:-                                                     
                                                                                                               
   return_code = subprocess.run(['sh', '1.bash']).returncode
  if return_code != 0:
     exit()                                                                                                 
                                                                                               and 1.bash calling another bash script where i put exit code 0

Comment: If 1.bash returns NOT 0 when you want the python script to stop it will work